# Forfiles command in For Loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, forfiles

Simplified working Script part from a Batch File

```
for %%F in 
(
C:\A\*.TXT
) do (
echo %%F
)
```

This prints out all .TXT filepaths from folder A.

I would like to add a forfiles extension in order to only get .TXT files /D -2

```
for %%F in ('
forfiles /P "C:\A\" /M *.TXT /D -2 /C "cmd /c echo @PATH"
') do 
(
echo %%F
)
```

But this only prints the forfiles command as string:

```
'forfiles
/P
"C:\A\"
/M
/D
-2
/C
"cmd /c echo @PATH"'
```

How do I have to hand over the forfiles command to make this work - if possible at all.

Comment: See @Dominique's answer for a solution. Just to explain your error: to process the output of a command, you need `for /f` (described in `for /?`) A plain `for` (like you did) just dissects a string into words (except there is a wildcard in a "word", then it will list all matching files (obviously you don't have any txt files in the current working folder))

Comment: There are too many line-breaks in your `for`-loops – such behind `in` or `do` is not acceptable…

Comment: @aschipfl I guess that are typing errors, as OP claims, both code snippets work (although not as intended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this and it works fine:

```
forfiles /M *.TXT /D -2 /C "cmd /c echo @file"
```

As you see, you don't need to add `forfiles` to your for-loop, because it replaces the for-loop.

In case you want this for all files inside subdirectories, you might add the `/S` switch:

```
forfiles /S /M *.TXT /D -2 /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

... and if you want to specify a directory, you might do this:

```
forfiles /P C:\ /S /M *.TXT /D -2 /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, to get your output, containing just each path double-quoted, you do not need a `for` loop.

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "C:\A" /M "*.txt" /D -2 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"If @IsDir == FALSE Echo @Path\""
```

Technically however, to get the same output as you would from:

```sh
for %%F in 
(
C:\A\*.TXT
) do (
echo %%F
)
```

i.e. not double-quoted, you would still need a `for` loop:

```sh
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "C:\A" /M "*.txt" /D -2 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"If @IsDir == FALSE Echo @Path\""') Do Echo %%~G
```

Or…

With `Echo Off`:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "C:\A" /M "*.txt" /D -2 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /Q /D /C \"If @IsDir == FALSE For %%G In (@Path) Do Echo %%~G\"" & Echo(
```

With `Echo On`:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "C:\A" /M "*.txt" /D -2 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"@If @IsDir == FALSE For %%G In (@Path) Do Echo %%~G\""
```